# HTTP Raw request default is throwing Response message:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout exceeded while reading from socket

Tags: tcp, jmeter, logstash

I sent a HTTP Raw request default with a host and port which I'm certain that I could connect using my windows 10 device.(Tested with Test-NetConnection and sent data via Ubuntu App, echo "DEMO Message" | nc mYHOST 6021)
However, when I sent the request in Jmeter , I get below errors.

Sampler result is as per the below.

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2021-09-17 15:55:08 IST
Load time:9300
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:921
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:921
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:500
Response message:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout exceeded while reading from socket


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Response is as per the below.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout exceeded while reading from socket
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout exceeded while reading from socket
    at kg.apc.io.SocketChannelWithTimeouts.read(SocketChannelWithTimeouts.java:133)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.HTTPRawSampler.readResponse(HTTPRawSampler.java:64)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.HTTPRawSampler.processIO(HTTPRawSampler.java:163)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.AbstractIPSampler.sample(AbstractIPSampler.java:112)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.HTTPRawSampler.sample(HTTPRawSampler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

This demo host and port is working though and I used exact same in my real request too.
[image]

Similar issues come when I use JSR223 Sampler with below code.

```
def client = new Socket('DemoHostname', 9000);
client.setSoTimeout(2000);
client << "Hello ";
client.withStreams { input, output ->
    def reader = input.newReader()
    def response = reader.readLine()
    log.info('Response = ' + response)
}
client.close()
```

Also with TCP Sampler of Jmter.

So  based on the suggestion, I sent it as a Http request  to  websocket  of **Logstash**.
Good thing is add the record get added,  but Jmter http request is running in an endless state. Seems since logstash communicate via TCP it's unable to provide a http response.

[image]

Comment: That's not a valid HTTP request. The server is probably waiting for the client to continue sending but the client does not. Both wait for each other until one times out. Note that the connection itself succeeded, only the reading from the server timed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve by sending `HELLO TEST` to `echo.websocket.org`?

If you want to send a [HTTP Request there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), you need to do something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: echo.websocket.org
Connection: close
```

Demo:

[image]

If you need to load test a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) server - you're using the wrong plugin, you should go for [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide/) instead and consider using more "alive" endpoint as this `echo.websocket.org` doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, It's for a just demonstration.  Actually I want to post to a logstash server via TCP. So  just now I sent the same request via normal Http request, the record is get added to the logstash but Jmter  request is still ongoing in an endless state.

Comment: If HTTP Request does the job just set a reasonable timeout, the setting is at the "Advanced" tab. If you don't want the failure to be present in JMeter logs - add a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) as a child of this request  configured to expect HTTP Status Code 500 with "Ignore status" box checked  and JMeter will treat that sampler as successful. The same approach can be used for any other Sampler. However you might want to come up with your own implementation of the AbstractTCPClient so JMeter won't "wait forever"

Comment: Thank  you  
Dmitri T, checked this with our Dev-ops team, since the logstash is not sending  the acknowledgement  response is received.  However, JSR223 Sampler is working and insert data in rapid sequence. So it 's managable. Thank you .

Comment: responseCode
500 is received but  the insertion was the main concern , so even without Jmeter pass status  report, we have alternatives to monitor the pass rate in Kibana.